# merge multiple anonymous users data with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my app user could work without sync todo list between devices. In that case i use `anonymous` user account. 
In `AppDelegate.swift` :

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
            if user != nil {
                print("User auth with account")
            } else {
                FIRAuth.auth()?.signInAnonymously() { (user, error) in
                    if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil {
                        print("User auth anonymously")
                    } else {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now if user wants to sync todo list he should log in. I do this with this function:

```
let credential = FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: self.textFieldLoginEmail.text!, password: self.textFieldLoginPassword.text!)
    FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.link(with: credential, completion: { user, error in
        if error == nil {
            FIRAuth.auth()!.signIn(withEmail: self.textFieldLoginEmail.text!,
                                   password: self.textFieldLoginPassword.text!)
        }
    })
```

I store todo-items in Firebase like:

```
todoitems
----user_id
--------todo-item_id
```

But all data from "anonymous" account has been lost, when i did login. Why? It should merge this "anonymous" account to existing and all its data. Or i should do this manually ?

Comment: what data do you expect to merge? do you mean user's account in Firebase? or in the database?

Comment: Data is data in Firebase and the data is never lost unless the data is deleted. The developer controls what data can be accessed. The question is super vague as in; what if there are 50 anonymous users - how would you know which data belongs to each anonymous user? Firebase doesn't have a merge function so coding an app to let the current user also access that anonymous data is a function of the code. Please clarify the question so we can try to answer it.

Comment: @Jay ok, sorry for unclear question. Each user has a todo list for example. So when I link account I should change every item owner to new user manually?

Comment: If you are using anonymous login, then each user is essentially the same user as they are all anonymous. What are you doing in code and Firebase structure to separate the To Do lists for each anonymous user? When the actual user logs in with a user account, how do you know which anonymous data belongs to that user?

Comment: Each anonymous and logged in user has his own unique id. So i save to do items like: ```if let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser { FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("todo-items").child(currentUser.uid).childByAutoId() }```

Comment: @Jay So i store data like:

todo-items

----user_id

--------todo-item_id

Comment: @Jad  i updated question

Comment: @Jad What do you mean by- "If you are using anonymous login, then each user is essentially the same user as they are all anonymous."? They are NOT essentially the same. Each anonymously authenticated user have their own unique UID.

Answer (score 1):

You should to link accounts, instead of signing in.
See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking